# How to download only the files modified in a changelist with perforce

Tags: perforce

How do i download only the set of files that are modified in a changelist. I was able to find the list of files modified with p4 describe.

Comment: Use `p4 print` to download each file.

Comment: (I consider this on topic because it is about a software development tool.)

Answer (score 1):

To sync them to your workspace, do:

```
p4 sync @=CHANGE
```

If you want to download them to arbitrary locations and/or stdout, see the `p4 print` command.